# Which movie is Natasha watching in Black Widow?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, black-widow-2021

In the movie *Black Widow* while living in the truck hiding from Thunderbolt Ross, Natasha watches a Bond movie. Which movie is she watching?

[image: Natasha watching a movie on a laptop. On the screen is a bearded man wearing a green suit, his arms folded behind his back. On either side of him are two men in yellow containment suits, holding weapons. In the background are two women wearing short white dresses.]

Comment: Note also Moonraker's ending.

Comment: Peter Dinklage self-starring in some arthouse film?

Comment: Pretty girls, skimpy outfits, good production values, 1970s vibe: definitely a Bond film.

Comment: @RonJohn - Or Austin Powers

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's *Moonraker*, the 1979 James Bond film featuring Roger Moore as Bond. You can tell by the villain, Hugo Drax, as played by Michael Lonsdale.

[image: Hugo Drax]

Comment: I was wondering why it had some James Bond-ish vibe to it.

Comment: As I recall Roger Moore was in the Black Widow clip too.